# Prove that the Fibonacci function $F(n)$ is NOT $\Omega(n)$

Tags: asymptotics, fibonacci-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

Is there a straightforward proof that follows directly from the definition of the Fibonacci sequence (i.e., $F(0)=1, F(1)= 1, F(n) = F(n-1)+F(n-2) \text{ for } n \geq 2$), without using, say, the closed-form expression?

Answer (score 6):

It's clear that the Fibonacci numbers are increasing, so
$$
F(n+2) > 2F(n).
$$

That's good enough to guarantee exponential growth.